# How to make a Secondary plot based on bins in a Histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-analysis

I have a column called `val_a` in my dataframe. I make a histogram plot of this variable. I also have a column called `row_accuracy` and I am trying to make a boxplot of the `row_accuracy` values as a function of the `val_a` bins (To be concrete, in the example below, I have three bins. A left bin with mostly negative values say between -10 to -3. I would like to take the `row_accuracy` values that correspond to this bin and plot a boxplot of the `row_accuracy` values above the plot of that bin). The code I have at the moment is shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {"val_a"       : [-10, -8, -6, -4, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
        "row_accuracy": [0.7, 0.8, 0.95, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.7, 0.85, 0.9], 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.hist(df['val_a'], bins = 3)
ax1 = ax.twinx()
```

edit:

I figured out how to get the corresponding values for `row_accuracy` by doing this

```
bins = pd.cut(df['val_a'], bins=3)
grouped = df.groupby(bins)['row_accuracy']
```

Right now I am just struggling with making the boxplots on the histogram plot.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to place an inset axes, like in this [demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axes_grid1/inset_locator_demo.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

data = {"val_a"       : [-10, -8, -6, -4, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
        "row_accuracy": [0.7, 0.8, 0.95, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.7, 0.85, 0.9], 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# group row_accuracy data according to 3 bins of val_a
bin_labels=['A', 'B', 'C']
bins = pd.cut(df['val_a'], bins=3, labels=bin_labels)
grouped = df.groupby(bins)['row_accuracy']
grouped_values = grouped.apply(list)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
# make a histogram of val_a
ax.hist(df['val_a'], bins = 3)

# slightly expand the plot limits to accommodate a small inset plot above the first bin from the left
min_x, max_x = ax.get_xlim()
min_y, max_y = ax.get_ylim()
min_x, max_x = ax.set_xlim(min_x - (max_x - min_x) * 0.1, max_x + (max_x - min_x) * 0.1)
min_y, max_y = ax.set_ylim(min_y, max_y + (max_y - min_y) * 0.7)

# find absolute coordinates and dimensions of the first bin
rects = ax.patches
b_height = rects[0].get_height()
b_width = rects[0].get_width()
b_x = rects[0].get_x()

# find relative coordinates and dimensions of the first bin
ax_width = (max_x - min_x)
ax_height = (max_y - min_y)
b_x_rel = (b_x - min_x) / ax_width
b_width_rel = b_width / ax_width
b_height_rel = b_height / ax_height

# create a small inset plot inside a bounding box in relative units of the big plot
axins = inset_axes(ax, width="100%", height="100%",
                   bbox_to_anchor=(b_x_rel, b_height_rel + 0.1, b_width_rel, 0.3),
                   bbox_transform=ax.transAxes, loc=3, borderpad=0)
# box plot row_accuracy values for the first bin
axins.boxplot(grouped_values['A'])
axins.xaxis.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

The result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of drawing the boxplots via a twin axis, I would suggest creating a different subplot. Via the `heigh_ratios` more space can be reserved for the boxplots.

Matplotlib's `boxplot` has `positions=` to position the center, e.g. at the center of the bin. And `widths=` to set the width, e.g. 80% of the width of the bin. `manage_ticks=False` prevents that matplotlib only marks the boxplots with x tick positions.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = {"val_a": [-10, -8, -6, -4, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
        "row_accuracy": [0.7, 0.8, 0.95, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.7, 0.85, 0.9]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True,
                               gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [3, 1], 'hspace': 0})
ax2.hist(df['val_a'], bins=3)
ax2.set_ylabel("Count")
ax2.set_xlabel("Val_a")

bins = pd.cut(df['val_a'], bins=3)
grouped = df.groupby(bins)['row_accuracy']
for bin, group in grouped:
    ax1.boxplot(group, positions=[bin.mid], widths=(bin.right - bin.left) * 0.8,
                patch_artist=True, manage_ticks=False)
ax1.set_ylabel("Accuracy")

plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib histogram with boxplot per bin]

If you really want, very similar code would drawn on a `twinx` ax, although the plot would be harder to interpret due to overlaps.